# Python: append copy of nested list to list

Tags: python, arrays, list, append, nested

In my code, I have the nested list `gamelist`, defined as

```
gamelist = [['3'], ['2'], ['1']]
```

The purpose of the program is to treat the internal lists as stacks, appending smaller elements to stacks containing larger elements or empty stacks, sweeping up and down the list and not repeating moves. Theoretically this game should go:

```
[['3'], ['2'], ['1']]
[['3'], ['2', '1'], []]
[['3', '1'], ['2'], []]
[['3', '1'], [], ['2']]
```

And so on, until the list is sorted from smallest to largest.

In order to check the current move against previous moves, I created `pastmoves`, which has a copy of `gamelist` appended to it after each move.

```
pastmoves.append(gamelist[:])
```

So `pastmoves` should read

```
[[['3'], ['2'], ['1']]]
[[['3'], ['2'], ['1'], [['3'], ['2', '1'], []]]
```

and so on after each consecutive move.

My issue is that while gamelist is being copied, the lists nested inside it are not, and `pastmoves` looks like this after two moves:

```
[[['3'], ['2', '1'], []], [['3'], ['2', '1'], []]]
```

I'd like to make it so that all of the bottom-level values are also copies and remain static as `gamelist` changes. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from copy import deepcopy

pastmoves.append(deepcopy(gamelist))
```

Comment: I guess I should probably read through the standard library. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is just to use `copy.deepcopy()` to do a deep copy on the nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `copy.deepcopy()`, here is how you can do this with a list comprehension:

```
pastmoves.append([inner[:] for inner in gamelist])
```

Note that this will only work for one level of nesting, if you have arbitrarily nested lists then `copy.deepcopy()` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Interesting value returned. `pastmoves` reads `[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x026E2E18>]`. I've never used list comprehensions before, so I don't know what's going on here.

Comment: Did you include the square brackets?

Answer (score 0):

Simple: `pastmoves.append( list(gamelist[:]) )`

Now each time new object will bew generated

Comment: That resulted in the same problem, I'm not sure why.

Comment: `list(gamelist)` will do the same thing as `gamelist[:]`, both are a shallow copy.  `list(gamelist[:])` will just do a shallow copy twice and the inner lists of the result will have the same identity as the ones from `gamelist`.

Comment: My tests are showing kinda different results:
     >>> a = [[1],[2],[3]]
     >>> b = list(a)
     >>> a
     [[1], [2], [3]]
     >>> b
     [[1], [2], [3]]
     >>> b[1]=[8]
     >>> a
     [[1], [2], [3]]
     >>> b
     [[1], [8], [3]]